# rasterio rasterize does not take geometry

Tags: raster, vector, rasterization, rasterio

```
rasterize(allshapes)  return;
```

"ValueError: No valid geometry objects found for rasterize"

Testung a single shape:

```
print(shape.GetGeomFieldRef(0))
POINT (56.91288 27.33519)

print(is_valid_geom(shape.geometry()))
False
```

in rasterios github the function checks for following :

```
geom_type = geom['type']
    if geom_type not in geom_types.union({'GeometryCollection'}):
        return False
```

cheking for this by hand :

```
print(shape.geometry()['type'])
TypeError: 'Geometry' object is not subscriptable
```

and for :

```
if 'type' not in geom:
    return False`
```

`

cheking by Hand also returnes False

Changing to Polygon wont help

`print(shape.geometry())
POLYGON ((....))`

`print(is_valid_geom(shape.geometry()))
False`

I dont get this, pls help

Comment: You need Polygons geometry and not Points

Comment: polygons wont work either

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pass a gdal/ogr geometry to rasterio? What is the output of `type(shape)`?  If so, this won't work.  From the [docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.features.html?highlight=rasterize#rasterio.features.rasterize) "*The geometry can either be an object that implements the geo interface or GeoJSON-like object.*".  Use `fiona` to read your geometry in.

Comment: fiona is not compatible with rasterio , since fiona needs GDAL 2.4 and rasterio needs GDAL 3.1; i haven´t found a wheel for a compatible rasterio

Comment: opened a new topic for the incompatibility issue https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334301/using-rasterio-and-fiona-not-possible

Comment: fiona works fine with rasterio. I don't know about wheels though, I use `conda` not `pip` to install.

Comment: reading the file with fiona returns a list of dictionaries; also these polygon files are no valid geometries

Comment: Just access the geometry property - `with fiona.open(path) as data_source:`  `for feat in data_source:`    `feat['geometry']`