# Installing rasterio and Fiona together?

Tags: gdal, installation, fiona, rasterio

I work on Windows; I use Christoph Gohlke wheels; Python 3.7

After installing `GDAL-3.0.1` and `Fiona-1.8.6`

an error occurs on import of fiona
`from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: DLL load failed:`

by downgrading to `GDAL-2.4.1` I could surpass the error, yet rasterio starts rasing an error :
`from rasterio._base import gdal_version
ImportError: DLL load failed:`

Comment: do you need both inside the same project? if not you could use separate virt_envs to handle the different gda lversions.

Comment: time to switch to conda and install these libs in separate environments from the conda-forge channel

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be that this cannot be done, at least using the current versions of both packages.  Because as, you noted, the latest versions of fiona and rasterio rely on different GDAL versions.  There is likely an older version of rasterio (1.0.*) that could use GDAL 2.4.1.

I have been using fiona (1.8.6), rasterio (1.0.22) and gdal (2.4.0) fine in my conda environment.  I wanted to use a new feature in rasterio (1.1.0) but this requires gdal (3.0.1) and but this is incompatible with any version of fiona.